# Python: "window" is not defined

Tags: python

```
import turtle

    windows = turtle.Screen()
    windows.bgcolor("black")``
    mini = turtle.Turtle()
    mini.shape("turtle")
    mini.color("yellow")
    mini.speed(0)
    for i in range (0,36):
        for j in range (2):
              mini.forward(100)
              mini.right(60)
              mini.forward(100)
              mini.right(120)
         mini.right(10)
     mini.right(90)
     mini.forward(150)

window.exitonclick()
```

Above is the code that I want to run in python 2.7.11 but it is showing "window" is not defined. The graphic output is shown but it closes as soon as the output is shown, I have tried opening it in cmd but it was of no use.

Comment: Your indentation is wrong, and you defined a variable named `windows`, not `window`.

Comment: Thanx...chepner and zondo, I really did not noticed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined `windows` but you are trying to access `window`.  It is indeed not defined.  You could use `windows.exitonclick()` instead, but you can also say `turtle.exitonclick()` which should do that for you.